# How to get derived class name from base class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is is possible to get derived class name from base constructor?

```
class Entity {
    constructor() {
         // how to log here a class?
         console.log('a')
    }
}
class a extends Entity {}
new a()
```

Comment: At the JavaScript level, `console.log(this.constructor.name)`. I don’t know if TypeScript provides something more static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can output the name of a function in JavaScript/TypeScript using [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript):

```js
class Entity {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name)
  }
}

class A extends Entity {}
const a = new A();
console.log(a.constructor.name);
```