# Conditional template in Angular with interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript, polymorphism

I want to render in the same page multiple `bloc`s that can be of multiple type, for example an **event**, a **location**, a **book**, etc..

I defined an interface for this, that I called a `Bloc`. And multiple extensions of this interface.

```js
export interface Bloc {
}

export interface BlocBook extends Bloc {
  name: string;
  image: string;
}

export interface BlocLocation extends Bloc {
  name: string;
  image: string;
}

export interface BlocEvent extends Bloc {
  name: string;
  location: Location;
  image: string;
}
```

The view must deal with `Bloc[]` and process them with a ***ngFor**.

I populate the array as follow :

```js
for (let event of resp['events']){
   var b = <BlocEvent>{
      name: event.name,
      image: event.location.image,
    };
}
```

But the thing is that the layout depends on the type of the bloc. If it is an  **event** I must display some information, if it is a **book** I must display other information.

For exemple, the **routerLink** to go to the detail page will not be the same. Or the **background color of the bootstrap card**.

All I have as of now is the `@Input` variable.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Bloc } from '../../../models/bloc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bloc',
  templateUrl: './bloc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bloc.component.css']
})
export class BlocComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bloc: Bloc;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How can I acheive this please ? Should I play with multiple ***ngIf** or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get an object's class name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime)

Comment: @Liam : hum not really, I mean, I do not see how it could help me because the conditional rendering should be performed on the template no ?

Comment: I guess it's a starting point for you. That gives you the mechanism to decide if it's a `book` or and `event`. The rest is just using [ngif](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngif-else/)

Comment: I will give it a try thanks

Comment: You could use [ngSwitch] instead of multiple *ngIfs