# Find type of an unknown objects

Tags: typescript, types

There are times when you need to work with packages which aren't built with typescript in mind. For example, I'm working with `two.js` package in a react + typescript project with strict mode turned on. I'm finding it very difficult to type each variable properly as I have no clue what a lot of functions return.

If I use `any` or don't mention a type, I get annoying errors like variable `implicitly has an 'any' type` and it feels like I'm in constant battle with the compiler instead of focusing on my work.

A lot of other languages have some function/keyword which gives you the exact class/type an object is based on. But in javascript's `typeof` & `instanceof` are completely useless as you can only use them to check *if* an object is of a certain class. And `typeof` simply returns `object` for any custom object.

I love typescript but this is very annoying. How do I get around this? I've tried googling online but couldn't find a solid way to deal with this problem.

Comment: typeof should return you the type as a string though, just console.log it no?

Comment: @laenNoCode no it just says "object"

Comment: i guess it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime
the solution is to use ".constructor.name"

Comment: @laenNoCode and how to I get return type of a function?

Comment: maybe just run it once. Some depending on if the library is a typescript library, vscode (or some other editors) might give you the documentation of it. Otherwise check the documentation if availible. That's how i do it

Answer (score 0):

> If I use `any` or don't mention a type, I get annoying errors like variable `implicitly has an 'any' type`

The message explains that the variable in question has no explicit annotation. This won't happen if you explicitly annotate/assert `any`.

---

If you want to keep your program type-safe, your only options are to

- create a [declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for the imported module, or
- use [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) when you use the untyped imports

There's not another way for TypeScript to know what the imported types are because TS is a [static](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#typescript-a-static-type-checker), [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) type checker, and its purpose is to help keep your program type-safe.