# Decorator to add a method which returns class name and the string passed in brackets

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, decorator

The task is to implement the class decorator to add the “identify“ class method which returns a class name with the information passed in the decorator.
Example:

```
@identifier('example')
    class Test {}
    
    const test = new Test();
    console.log(test['identify']()); // Test-example
```

Unit tests:

```
describe('identifier', () => {
    it('should return Test-example from identify', () => {
        @identifier('example')
        class Test {}
        const test = new Test();
        assert.strictEqual(test['identify'](), 'Test-example');
    });

    it('should return ClassA-prototype from identify', () => {
        @identifier('prototype')
        class ClassA {}
        const test = new ClassA();
        assert.strictEqual(test['identify'](), 'ClassA-prototype');
    })
```

I tried to do something with this decorator,but what i have now is only console logging the string passed in brackets,i have no idea how to print the class name where decorator is used.. Please help. :
My function :

```
function identifier(passedInformation:string):string {
  console.log('-'+passedInformation)
}
```

Edit :
I almost did the function :

```
function identifier(...args: any): ClassDecorator {
    return function <TFunction extends Function>(
        target: TFunction
    ): TFunction | void {
        return target.name+'-'+args)
    }
}
```

if i change the `return target.name+'-'+args` with console log,it gives the result expected in unit test logged in console,but the problem is that i get :  *type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void | TFunction'*
And this in junit.xml :

```
<failure message="" type="TypeError"><![CDATA[TypeError: 
    at DecorateConstructor (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:544:31)
    at Object.decorate (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:130:24)
    at __decorate (test\index.ts:4:92)
```

But if i change the return to console log,i get this in junit.xml:

```
<failure message="test.identify is not a function" type="TypeError"><![CDATA[TypeError: test.identify is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.ts:99:44)
```

What is wrong? How can i return my result and finish this task?

Edit 2 :
Using @Vallarasu SambathKumar solution below,i dont get any errors in the code editor,but in junit.xml i get next errors and it can not pass the unit test.. :

```
 <failure message="" type="TypeError"><![CDATA[TypeError: 
    at DecorateConstructor (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:544:31)
    at Object.decorate (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:130:24)
    at __decorate (test\index.ts:4:92)
    at C:\Users\artio\Desktop\6 Decorators\decorators\test\index.ts:81:20
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.ts:85:10)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>
```

How to fix this,whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Vallarasu SambathKumar solution  and a little more documentation,i came up with this function :

```
function identifier(...args: any): ClassDecorator {
    return function <TFunction extends Function>(
        target: TFunction
    ): TFunction | any {
        var identify = target.prototype.identify;
        Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'identify', {
            value: function() {
                return target.name + "-" + args;
            }
        });
        return identify;
    };
}
```

I did the identify method like the task needed and then returned it,no errors at unit tests and at run time,perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You may as well pass instance as a parameter and access it's type

```
function identifier(passedInformation:string) {
    return function (target) {
        console.log(target.constructor.name + '-'+passedInformation);
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
test['identify'](test)
```

improvised from - [Get an object's class name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime)

Comment: It console logs what i need,but it doesnt pass the unit tests,i edited my question with the function i have did till now,but have to fix the errors..

Comment: The error is with the inner functions return type switch to string should help 

TFunction | void -> String

Comment: I switched and got the whole list of errors :  Type '<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | String' is not assignable to type 'ClassDecorator'.
  Type 'String | TFunction' is not assignable to type 'void | TFunction'.
    Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'void | TFunction'.
      Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'TFunction'.
        'TFunction' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'String'.

Comment: Idk whats the problem,using your solution it console logs everything good,i dont get any errors,but in junit.xml i get the following errors :   **<failure message="" type="TypeError"><![CDATA[TypeError: 
    at DecorateConstructor (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:544:31)
    at Object.decorate (node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:130:24)
    at __decorate (test\index.ts:4:92)
    at C:\Users\artio\Desktop\6 Decorators\decorators\test\index.ts:81:20
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.ts:85:10)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)]]></failure>**

Comment: It must be with return value,  A class decorator is expected to return [1] value of type it decorates, or [2] constructor function for the same. In the code above returns a string value. Do you intend to cache this value in a member for later use like below?

>> target['id'] = target.constructor.name + '-'+ passedInformation

Comment: I dont think that i will use it before,it is just for passing the task,but if this will help to get rid of the error then we can do it