# How to get class name without instance in Typescripts

Tags: typescript, object

I'd like to get class name without instance.
But it does not work well.
[Here is my test code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNH0CWAJgIQBcAdgK4C2ARsgNxa7RlhUKkQAuSeZA5lgC%20WLMAD2ZbtCQUy0ALzQAFOJLiaAKwTAuASkUA%20NE1wSp4kAgB0Icf1XXW7PY0wjMWWWWXxkrrzllMgQAdzhEJADMIA)

```
class User {
    id!:number;
    name!:string
}

//It should use object type. Not used User type directly.
const run = (o:object) => {
    console.log(o.constructor.name);
}

run(User); 
//It printed as Function. 
//But, I'd like to class name(aka, User) without instance(new User)
```

How can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get an object's class name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `o.name` instead of `o.constructor.name`

```js
class User {
    id!:number;
    name!:string
}

const run = (o: any) => {
    console.log(o.name);
}

run(User);
```

Source: [Get an object's class name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime)

Comment: When I tested it in my test code(I've linked it in my question), it occur error as "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'."

Comment: @seans One way to work around it would be to use type `any` instead of `object` like so: `const run = (o:any) => {...}`

Comment: If you want it to work for both instances and non-instances, refer to @RahulSharma answer below. I excluded the solution for instances because you said "I'd like to get class name without instance."

Answer (score 1):

If `o` is an `object` use `o.constructor.name` otherwise `o.name`.

```
class User {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const run = (o: any) => {
    typeof o === 'object' ? console.log(o.constructor.name) : console.log(o.name);
}

run(User);                     // 'User'
run(new User('john doe'));     // 'User'
```