# Parsing Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array as a attribute on a link.

Here is the array

```
images="["one.jpg","two.jpg"]"
```

How would I parse through this array and have it read back to me one.jpg,two.jpg?

This is what I am doing now and it is giving me an error back. I don't believe json parsing is whats needed here.

```
var imgs = $("#"+number).attr("images");
var imgList = jQuery.parseJSON(imgs);
```

EDIT: ACTUAL CODE

```
var number = $(this).attr("data-id");

var url = $("#"+number).attr("url");
$(".portfolio-url").html("<h3 class='pacifico'>url</h3><p><a href='http://"+url+"' target='_blank'>"+url+"</a></p>");

var cli = $("#"+number).attr("client");
$(".portfolio-client").html("<h3 class='pacifico'>client</h3><p>"+cli+"</p>");

var pgs = $("#"+number).attr("pages");
pgs = pgs.replace(/\[/g,"");
pgs = pgs.replace(/\]/g,"");
pgs = pgs.replace(/\"/g,"");
var pages = new Array();
pages = pgs.split(",");

var img = $("#"+number).attr("images");
img = img.replace(/\{/g,"");
img = img.replace(/\}/g,"");
img = img.replace(/\"/g,"");
var images = new Array();
images = img.split(",");

var portSkills = "<h3 class='pacifico'>skills</h2>";
portSkills += "<p>";
for (i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
if (pages[i] != "Clients") {
var finalPage = "";
for (j=0;j<pages[i].length;j++)
{
var ch = pages[i].charAt(j);
if (ch == ch.toUpperCase()) {
finalPage += " ";
}
finalPage += pages[i].charAt(j);
}
portSkills += finalPage+"<br />";
}
}
portSkills += "</p>";
$(".portfolio-skills").html(portSkills);

var imgs = $("#"+number).attr("images");
var imgList = jQuery.parseJSON(imgs);
```

Basically, its looping through parameters

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing array-syntax as the value of an attribute?

Comment: Is that the real code? The double quotes around the `[]` are going to break it.

Comment: Yes, its the real code. I've been going through someone else's code trying to problem solve a few issues.

Comment: Start by changing either the outer or the inner quotes to single quotes.  Then, you can retrieve the attribute value (your code is correct), and then you can parse the JSON into an array. Once the quoting is fixed, your method should work as you have already attempted it.

Comment: This is neither a valid array nor a valid attribute on an element

Comment: @wowzuzz Show us the actual code, copied and pasted. What you provided here would most definitely cause errors with the unescaped `"` characters.

Comment: This is not your actual code, it will just throw syntax errors. You take it from some HTML, post that HTML.

Comment: @wowzuzz This is your JavaScript. Where is your HTML showing the images attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd encourage you to modify your attribute-value format to something along these lines:

```
<div id="one" data-images="file1.jpg,file2.jpg">Foo, Bar</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note here I'm using a valid `data-` attribute, and the value of this attribute is just a list of comma-separated filenames. No need to place `[` or `]` in this value in order to get an array.

Now, to get your array:

```
var images = $("#one").data("images").split(",");
```

Which results in the following array:

```
["file1.jpg", "file2.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put that kind of string in the attribute, you could just put a comma separated string instead. (And you could use data attribute.)

For example:

```
<a id="foo" data-images="one.jpg,two.jpg">foo</a>
```

then you could get it by:

```
var imgList = $('#foo').data('images').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
}
```

Comment: You've also missed the point. it's a _string_ that takes the form of an array literal.

Comment: I thought he mistyped the code, cause he actually spoke about an array :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

`images = ["one.jpg", "two.jpg"];` is an array, yours is invalid.

to have it read back to you

```
for(image in images)
    console.log(images[image]);
```

or the jQuery way

```
$.each(images, function(index){
        console.log(images[index]);
});
```

if its a String that you need to split
then but that is of course if the string looks like this

```
var img = '["one.jpg", "two.jpg"]';

var images = img.replace(/\[|\]|"| /g,'').split(',');
```

this will give you an array parsed from a string that looks like an array.

Comment: You're missing the point. The value is a _string_ stored in an attribute called `images`

Comment: Yeah, I hit the send button a bit too quick :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the `join()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) a try:

```
images.join();

=> "one.jpg,two.jpg"

images.join(", ");

=> "one.jpg, two.jpg"
```

**Edit:** To declare your `Array`:

```
var images = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];
```

or

```
var images = new Array("img1", "img2", "img3");
```

Then you can use the `join()` method, and if that still doesn't work, try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript):

```
// should be true, if not then you don't have an Array
var isArray = (images instanceof Array);
```

Comment: When I do this it gives me the error code in developer tools.

Uncaught TypeError: Object ["Equipment-L.jpg","Equipment-web2-L.jpg","EquipmentL.jpg"] has no method 'join'

Comment: How are you declaring your array? See this [MDN guide on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).