# How to check if an argument is an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know just about everything is considered an object in JavaScript. I am making a function which specifically requires the argument it accepts to be in this format:

```
{
   a: 'b',
   c: 'd'
}
```

So this type of key value pair inside curly braces sort of object not the other type of objects. How to validate for this specifically?

Comment: This has been answered many many times: `{}.toString.call(obj) == "[object Object]"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: @elclanrs For some reason, the Chrome console doesn't like the dot in `{}.toString`

Comment: Try: `({}).toString` or `Object.prototype.toString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: After writing all of the below and later giving it further thought, I'd like to suggest that you take another look at [Trevor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825484/1202830). I think it is more deserving of that beautiful green checkmark than my answer, and here's why.

I took your question at face value and ran with it: If you really want to do literally what you said, a function like `$.isPlainObject()` is the way to go. But is that *really* what you need to do? Keep in mind that `$.isPlainObject()` is not a very efficient function; it enumerates through all your object's properties. And as I noted below, it can't distinguish between `{}` and `new Object()`.

Instead of all that, Trevor suggests simply checking for the properties you need, and for most cases, most of the time, I think he's right. It's definitely closer to the approach I take in my own code: validate what I need, ignore the rest.

So do take another look at his answer and carefully consider it. (And I won't be offended if you move the checkmark!)

Now my original answer:

There's a [`$.isPlainObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) function in jQuery. If you're not using jQuery, you can copy the source code for this function into your app. Open the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) and search for `isPlainObject:`.

It's worth reading the source for this function in any case, to see that it isn't as simple as an `typeof` or `instanceOf` check:

```
isPlainObject: function( obj ) {
    // Must be an Object.
    // Because of IE, we also have to check the presence of the constructor property.
    // Make sure that DOM nodes and window objects don't pass through, as well
    if ( !obj || jQuery.type(obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        // Not own constructor property must be Object
        if ( obj.constructor &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj, "constructor") &&
            !core_hasOwn.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf") ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // IE8,9 Will throw exceptions on certain host objects #9897
        return false;
    }

    // Own properties are enumerated firstly, so to speed up,
    // if last one is own, then all properties are own.

    var key;
    for ( key in obj ) {}

    return key === undefined || core_hasOwn.call( obj, key );
},

type: function( obj ) {
    if ( obj == null ) {
        return String( obj );
    }
    return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
        class2type[ core_toString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
        typeof obj;
},

isWindow: function( obj ) {
    return obj != null && obj == obj.window;
},
```

And there is also the `class2type` object that this code uses:

```
// [[Class]] -> type pairs
class2type = {},

// Populate the class2type map
jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});
```

(These code snippets are out of context; you'd need to tweak the syntax if you were using them standalone.)

Of course depending on the circumstances, you may not need *all* of these checks. And if you're using jQuery already, you can just call `$.isPlainObject()` and not sweat the details.

Also note that it is not possible to distinguish an object literal from an object created with `new Object`:

```
var obj1 = { a:'b', c:'d' };

var obj2 = new Object();
obj2.a = 'b';
obj2.c = 'd';

console.log( $.isPlainObject(obj1) );  // prints true
console.log( $.isPlainObject(obj2) );  // also prints true!
```

They both return `true` from `$.isPlainObject()`, and I'm pretty sure that any other test you devise will be unable to tell which is which either.

A funny historical note: When John Resig added this function to jQuery back in 2009, he was originally going to call it `$.isObjectLiteral()`. At my urging he [changed the name](http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/ajax-feature-matrix-td140894i40.html) to `$.isPlainObject` because of this ambiguity.

Comment: Yea I am using jquery, this will do.

Answer (score 1):

by using typeof

```
var obj = {x: 1, y: 2};
if (typeof obj == 'object') console.log('im an object');
```

Comment: `var obj = [1,2]; // typeof obj == object`

Answer (score 1):

This checks whether `value` is an `object` and wether it has properties `a` and `c`:

```
var value = {a: 1, c: 2};
if (typeof value === "object" && "a" in value && "c" in value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This good for checking that the properties you care about are there, because an array is also an object. `typeof [] === 'object'`

Comment: `var value = [1,2]; value.a = 1; typeof value === "object" && "a" in value // true`

Comment: @elclanrs Haven't you just converted the array to an object though?

Comment: @Phil: It's still an array, it has all array methods available, try it. It just has a property without index. Not recommended to do that but proves this answer wrong.

Comment: "… specifically requires the argument it accepts to be in this format…" The OP doesn't *really* want an object that's absolutely not an array; he just wants something that has properties a and c. In my opinion, this is the best solution to the OP's *actual* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pitfalls:

- `typeof` of Arrays is 'object'

  ```
  typeof [] === 'object' //true
  ```
- `Array` is an instance of `Object`

  ```
  Array instanceof Object //true
  ```
- `typeof null` is 'object'

  ```
  typeof null === 'object' //true
  ```

You can do this which checks if:

- `arg` is truthy. Since `null` is falsy, it's weeded here.
- `typeof arg` is 'object'. AFAIK, only arrays and objects pass on this one.
- finally, if `arg` is not instance of `Array`

  ```
  if(arg && typeof arg === 'object' && !(arg instanceof Array){...}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you've described, I wouldn't worry about making sure it's *not* an array or some other kind of object. Just make sure the properties you need are there, and if they're missing, sound the alarm.

```
function needAandC(params) {
    if (params.a === undefined || params.c === undefined)
        throw new Error('Ahhh.');

    // You've got what you need, don't worry what else is there.
}
```

Comment: I think you are right! In fact, I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15825328/1202830) to recommend your approach instead unless the stricter validation is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what exactly you want to assert. As for most common case - parameter (or contract) validation, I recently noticed NPM team (https://github.com/npm/cli) relies on https://github.com/iarna/aproba function, which freakishly lightweight and simple:

```
validate("O", [ val ]); // if val is not object, throws an exception
```

What the function does:

```
var isObject = ( typeof val === 'object' && val !== null && !Array.isArray( val ) 
  &&  !( val instanceof Error ) && !isArguments( val ) );

function isArguments (thingy) {
  return thingy != null && typeof thingy === 'object' && thingy.hasOwnProperty('callee')
}
```