# Print name of constructor variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, constructor

Say, I have 2 constructors assigned to 2 variables:

```
var example1 = function(argument1){
    this.argument1 = argument1;
}

var example2 = function(argument2){
    this.argument2 = argument2;
}
```

And an array of objects containing objects from both of these constructors:

```
var array1 = new Array();
array1[0] = new example1(example);
array1[1] = new example2(example);
```

My question is, when I choose an item from the array, how can I print the name of the constructor variable it came from?

To make this clear and succint, here's an example:

```
console.log(array1[0].argument1)
```

Will print *example*. But I don't want that. I want it to print the name of the constructor variable it came from.

```
console.log(array1[0].constructor.toString());
```

Prints the content of the variable, but it is unsatisfactory.

Comment: You could use function declarations, which created named function (with a `.name` property). Not sure if standard and/or cross-browser though. checking...

Comment: Your functions don't have *names* -- they are contained inside of variables. A function could be contained inside of multiple variables, e.g., `foo = bar = function() { }`, so it's not possible to find a canonical variable that contains a function. You can, however, gives names to your functions like `function example1() { }` which is accessible with the `name` property.

Comment: maybe duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: @fmodos That question refers to a type, not to a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a name to a function:-

```
var example1 = function example1(argument1){
    this.argument1 = argument1;
}
 var array1 = new Array();
array1[0] = new example1({});

console.log(array1[0].constructor.name)
```

Comment: var name = array1[0].constructor.name.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)[1];

Use the above regex for IE support.

Comment: This is a good one, unfortunately I just tested this on IE and it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this:-
array1[0].constructor.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)[1];

Comment: For IE9:  if(!String.name){ Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "name", {get: function(){   return String(this).split("(")[0].split(" ")[1]||"anon" }});}

Comment: @dandavis 
this works in every IE browser

array1[0].constructor.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)[1];

Comment: @pvnarula I tested that on every major browser. Seems to work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

in most browsers, functions have a name, but you don't use it.
so, we have to resort to hacks to find your constructor in the cloud, which won't work in IE7, maybe 8:

```
console.log(Object.keys(self).filter(function(a){
     return self[a]===array1[0].constructor;
})[0]);
```

if you didn't have the code running in the global scope, this trick won't work!
again, this is a hack and you should find a better way of doing things, like naming your functions, even if they are expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try instance of,

```
var example1 = function(argument1){
    this.argument1 = argument1;
}

var example2 = function(argument2){
    this.argument2 = argument2;
}

console.log(getName(array1[0]));

function getName(value) {

    if (value instanceof example1) return 'example1';
    if (value instanceof example2) return 'example2';

    return '';

}
```