# Why javascript typeof returns always "object"

Tags: javascript, typeof

Where am I doing wrong?

I would wait "Class" as a result of this code but it doesn't:

[image]

This is from object function:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Tyepof doesnt work like that, it only returns built in types. You could try:

```
this.constructor.name==="Class";
```

It will check all the way up the prototype chain to see if `this` or any prototype of `this` is Class. So if `OtherType.prototype=Object.create(Class);` then it'll be true for any OtherType instances. Does NOT work in < IE9

or

```
this instanceof Class
```

But that will not check the entire prototype chain.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a list of return values typeof can return

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript/332429#332429) is an answer about getting the type of a variable that has much more detail and shows many ways it can break.

Comment: Also instanceof has hidden catch when you try to check object from different window, i.e. from iframe.

Comment: @Tommi Yea, I'll add pavel's link to my answer as well because that is far more detailed

Answer (score 2):

Because JavaScript knows only the following types :

Undefined - "undefined"

Null - "object"

Boolean - "boolean"

Number - "number"

String - "string"

Host object (provided by the JS environment) - Implementation-dependent

Function object (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms) - "function"

E4X XML object - "xml"

E4X XMLList object - "xml"

Any other object - "object"

You can find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) thread to find how you can get the object name

Answer (score 1):

`object.constructor.name` will return constructor's name. Here is an example:

```
function SomeClass() {
    /* code */
}
var obj = new SomeClass();
// obj.constructor.name == "SomeClass"
```

Be aware that you need to use named functions, if you assign anonymous functions to variables, it will be an empty string...

```
var SomeClass = function () {
    /* code */
};
var obj = new SomeClass();
// obj.constructor.name == ""
```

But you can use both, then the named function's name will be returned

```
var SomeClassCtor = function SomeClass() {
    /* code */
};
var obj = new SomeClassCtor();
// obj.constructor.name == "SomeClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well

```
function getType(obj){
    if (obj === undefined) { return 'undefined'; }
    if (obj === null) { return 'null'; }
    return obj.constructor.name || Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).split(' ').pop().split(']').shift().toLowerCase();
}
```

[**An Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQyHx/)

```
function MyClass(){}
console.log(getType(new MyClass)); // MyClass
console.log(getType([])); // Array
console.log(getType({})); // Object
console.log(getType(new Array)); // Array
console.log(getType(new Object)); // Object
console.log(getType(new Date)); // Date
console.log(getType(new Error));  // Error
```

Comment: `obj === undefined` halts my script screaming obj is undefined so I cannot test against it :-)
So it would be worth adding following to your tests:
`console.log(getType(some_undefined_variable));  // should return undefined but does not on all browsers`