# Error in Javascript "constructor" property - IE 8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble with the following piece of code. The error occurs in the last line:

> return p_Function.constructor.name + "(" + v_args + ")";

When I run it on Internet Explorer 8, the function returns **undefined()**. Howerver, it works perfectly for Google Chrome (returning **FunctionName()**). I think it's a problem with the "constructor" property, but I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm new to JavaScript, and I'd be glad if I could get some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

```
getFunctionExecutionString: function(p_Function){
        var v_args = "";
        if(p_Function.arg) {
            for(var k=0; k < p_Function.args.length; k++) {
                if(typeof  p_Function.args[k] == "string"){
                    v_args += "\"" + p_Function.args[k].replace(/'/g, "") + "\",";
                }
                else{
                    v_args += p_Function.args[k] + ",";
                }
            }
            v_args = trim(v_args,",");
        }

               return p_Function.constructor.name + "(" + v_args + ")";
     }
  };
```

Comment: I don't think `constructor.name` (or rather `Function.name`) works in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: Side Question: Do you use eval() in the next step...that looks scary.

Comment: @epascarello, I didn't write the code, I'm just solving compatibility bugs.

Comment: @Bizzys: This won't work in IE.  Functions don't have the `name` property.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: then, how can I get the function name? I need this to work in IE.

Comment: @Bizzys: By finding the person who wrote `getFunctionExecutionString` and telling them their design is horrible! :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

```
return p_Function.constructor.toString().match(/function (.{1,})\(/)[1] + "(" + v_args + ")";
```

Example:

```
var A = function A(){};
var a = new A();
console.log(a.constructor.toString().match(/function (.{1,})\(/)[1]);
```