# To find type of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check the type of an variable in my method as below

```
var prevDate=new Date(2000, 2, 2)
console.log(typeof prevDate);
```

now the it returns "object" as type, but it is the type of date. how can i get the type of prevDate using **"typeOf"** and dont want to use the jQuery.type(prevDate), as it takes more time to execute.

Thanks In advance

Comment: I think you want the class name of the object. A good answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: if you want it the fast way `if (prevDate instanceof Date) ...` might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by following:

```
var prevDate=new Date(2000, 2, 2)
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(prevDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

The typeof works sufficiently well with primitive values (except null). But it says nothing about object types.
Fortunately, there is a hidden [[Class]] property in all JavaScript native objects. It equals “Array” for arrays, “Date” for dates etc.
This property is not accessible directly, but toString, borrowed from native Object returns it with a small wrapping, for example:

```
var toClass = {}.toString

alert( toClass.call( [1,2] ) ) // [object Array]
alert( toClass.call( new Date ) ) // [object Date]
```

You can read more [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection)

Answer (score 0):

one line function :

```
console.log( function(prevDate) {
  return ({}).toString.call(prevDate).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) returns a string representing the object.

```
var prevDate=new Date(2000, 2, 2);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(prevDate));

Output: "[object Date]"
```