# determining the type of a javascript object instance

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to determine the type of a JavaScript object?

See the example below for more context:

```
var Cat = function() {this.numEyes=2;this.numLegs=4};
var c = new Cat();
```

How do we determine the type of c.

I am not looking for

```
(c instanceof Cat)
```

Essentially how would I get the string Cat given c.

Comment: Please. var Cat = function.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [original post formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20519847/1) still visible in the revision history, `Cat` was defined without `var`, i.e.:

```
Cat = function() {this.numEyes=2;this.numLegs=4};
```

In this case, the constructor's name can be determined by iterating over the properties of the global object (`window` for browsers).

```
Cat = function() {this.numEyes=2;this.numLegs=4};
var c = new Cat();
alert(typeNameOf(c));

function typeNameOf(c) {
    for (name in window) {
        if (window[name] == Object.getPrototypeOf(c).constructor) return name;
    }
}
```

This should alert "Cat" in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after the constructor name and not the type. Problem is the way you defined it will not work.

```
var Cat = function (){}; 
var c = new Cat(); 
console.log(c.constructor.name);  //""
```

If you name your function, you can get the name

```
var Dog = function Dog(){}; 
var d = new Dog(); 
console.log(d.constructor.name);  //Dog
```

Comment: As a note, this does not work in IE (no `name` property support).