# How to check if DriveApp.getFolderById() returns a folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

When I use DriveApp.getFolderById(someId) where `someId` belongs to a file and not a folder, the method returns the file instead of erring out. How can I ensure that the returned object is indeed a folder?

Right now, the only solution I can think of is with try/catch:

```
try {
  const testFile = someFile.makeCopy('test', folder);
  testFile.setTrashed(true);
} catch (err) {
  return 'The folder is not really a folder';  
}
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(); if(folder)......

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to get the object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20664528/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, for example, how about checking the mimeType as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
const id = "###"; // Please set the file ID and folder ID.

const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.FOLDER) {
  console.log(`This ID (${id}) is a folder.`);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);

  // Do something.

} else {
  console.log(`This ID (${id}) is not a folder.`);
}
```

- When this script is run, by checking the mimeType of `id`, you can see whether the ID is the folder.

#### Reference:

- [getMimeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getmimetype)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> A folder doesn't have a getMimeType function to call, so I guess a check like if (!folder.getMimeType) that a returns true indicates that it's a folder.

If you want to check using `const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const id = "###"; // Please set the file ID and folder ID.

const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
if (folder.getUrl().split("/")[4] == "folders") {
  console.log(`This ID (${id}) is a folder.`);

  // In this case, you can directly use the variable of "folder".
  // Do something.

} else {
  console.log(`This ID (${id}) is not a folder.`);
}
```

- In this sample script, by checking the URL of the object, it is checked whether `id` is the folder. For example, when `id` is Spreadsheet, the retrieved URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit?usp=drivesdk`. This script uses this situation.

Comment: Thank you. A folder doesn't have a getMimeType function to call, so I guess a check like if (!folder.getMimeType) that a returns true indicates that it's a folder.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `A folder doesn't have a getMimeType function to call, so I guess a check like if (!folder.getMimeType) that a returns true indicates that it's a folder.`, it's yes. So I proposed to use `getFileById` method at `const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)`. From your reply, I thought that you might test `const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getMimeType()`. If it's so, such error occurs. So can you test my proposed script? If I misunderstood your reply, I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Ben From `A folder doesn't have a getMimeType function to call, so I guess a check like if (!folder.getMimeType) that a returns true indicates that it's a folder.`, if you want to use `DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`, how about the additional sample script? But, if this was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize again.

Comment: The sample script works great, thank you!