# Information I seem to only be able to get in the console which I need to use in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console, createjs

Here's the situation. I have the following line of code:

```
console.log(contents.storeShapes_mc.children[i]);
```

which prints out in the console like so:

```
lib.Store106II {id: 137, _matrix: a, _rectangle: a, children: Array[2], shape: a…}
```

I want to retrieve `lib.Store106II` to use in my JavaScript, but the console seems to be the one and only place I can get my hands on this particular string of data.  Is there any way to access this information from inside the code?

Notes: 
(1) I am using content created in Flash, exported for EaselJS
(2) Due to the syntax Toolkit for CreateJS implements, all of the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript/332429#332429) does not help me, unfortunately.

Edit:
Here is the javascript that "Toolkit for CreateJS" exported from Flash to create this object, along with dozens of similar objects:

```
(lib.Store106II = function() {
this.initialize();

// Layer 1
this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape.graphics.f().s("#DDE0CE").ss(1,0,0,4).p("AgGE4IEyjjIkfmLIk4Dlg");

this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_1.graphics.f("#A0A67C").s().p("AkrhRIE4jmIEfGMIkyDjg");

this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-30,-31.1,60.2,62.4);

/* some other code */

this.s106II = new lib.Store106II();    

/* s106II is eventually added as an element of storeShapes_mc 
which is in turn added as an element of contents */
```

Comment: Can we see the code that shows how you got that element?

Comment: @JanDvorak, I just edited the question to add the code you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With great thanks to fkranenburg on the CreateJS community support forums, I have found the answer to my question!  http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/4568-is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-an-array-of-all-the-custom-classes-created-in-the-lib-namespace

```
    for ( libname in lib ) { 
        lib[libname].prototype.className = libname;
    }
```

This loop cycles through the `lib` namespace (you can do that, apparently!) and retrieves the names of all the constructors created in that namespace.  Then, using dynamic referencing (aka square bracket notation, aka array notation) I reference each constructor in that namespace by name and access its prototype to add a new property named `className` to objects created by that constructor which returns the name of the object's constructor!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are calling console.log from inside flash?
If so you need to call a function from in flash and pass the function the data you want: `contents.storeShapes_mc.children[i]`

Then you store the data in a variable and that can be used to query the object and return whatever you need.

But will need an example of what you are using to get a better understanding.

**--Edit--**

Might have misunderstood slightly but if you're calling

```
console.log(contents.storeShapes_mc.children[i]);
```

can you not simply do the following:

```
var obj = contents.storeShapes_mc.children[i];
console.log(obj.id);
console.log(obj._matrix);
etc...
```

Comment: I don't see any flash mentioned?

Comment: `Notes: 1) I am using content created in Flash`

Comment: another case of: you should not stop reading in the before the last paragraph;)

Comment: @EliStone, thanks for your response, but I'm afraid I probably wasn't clear enough in my question.  I used the "Toolkit for CreateJS" export tool in Flash, but I'm doing all my programming in javascript. Also, I can access `id`, `_matrix`, etc. That's not what I'm interested in. I'm interested in `lib.Store106II` which seems to only be accessible through the console. But I don't want it in the console, I want it within my javascript logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your object has the following structure:

```
var contents = {
    "storeShapes_mc": {
        "children": [
            {
                "lib": {
                    "Store106II": {
                        "id": 137,
                        /* other stuff */
                    }
                }
            }, /* possibly other stuff*/
        ], /* possibly other stuff*/
    }
}
```

Now *if* you know the name of the properties `lib` and `Store106II` you can write:

```
var obj = contents.storeShapes_mc.children[0];

console.log(obj.lib); // to access Store106II 
// or something like this
console.log(obj.lib.Store106II.id);
```

Otherwise you have to [iterate through the Object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) and pick the one you think is the correct one.

If I misunderstood you, please tell me;)

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my situation.  I've included the javascript that defines this object.  Thanks.