# To get derived class name from Base class method

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to get the name of derived type from base class method.I have classes as below:

```
export class Base{   
    public Add(value: any) {

    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public Add(value: any) {
        Base.prototype.Add.call(this, value);
    } 
}
```

I tried using $.type(this) inside Add() of Base class which gives type as object.But while debugging code type of this is shown as "Object (Derived)".

Is there any way to get this??

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is your reason in doing this is? There might be a better way of doing things than the base class being aware of the derived class' name.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the name property of constructor, like so:

```
class Base {   
    public Add(value: any) {
        alert(this.constructor["name"]); // alerts 'Derived' in this example
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public Add(value: any) {
        super.Add(value); // use super to call methods on the base class
    }
}

(new Derived).Add('someValue');
```

Comment: Note that this is not actually possible if you use minification of your javascript as your class will be renamed to something like `a`. You will have to use a string value to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

*First*, you've not defined inheritance in your snippet. Use `extends` to create class inheritance in *Typescript*.

```
class Derived extends Base {
..
```

*Second* - to access base class you can use `super` keyword:

```
public Add(value: any) {
   super.Add.call(this, value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry.I just left to put extends.Now i have edited my code.Is there any way to get derived class name??

Comment: @SwarnaLatha Look at [How to get object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Each Object has a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) function and you can look at its name property.

```
class Alpha { }
var a = new Alpha();
alert((<any>a).constructor.name);  // Alpha
```

link

You'll note I had to cast `a` to `any`.  The `constructor` property isn't defined in lib.d.ts and I assume that's because its use is discouraged.  Minification will also change the result.  I would only use this for debugging purposes.