# Searching for an instance of a custom object

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I want to check if my javascript object is of a certain type.

I have an object (I cannot edit this object.) and I have made instances of that object. Now I want to loop through all the objects that are available at any given point and figure out which ones are the instances that I am looking for.

Example:

```
var myObject = function() { };
var obj_person = new myObject();
```

Now if I write

```
typeof obj_person
```

It gives me `object` which is not useful. I cannot use `instanceof` as it does not work in IE8.

Is there anyway to check if obj_person is an instance of myObject?

Thanks.

EDITED*****

Here is the code

```
var arr_instances = [];
for(var v in window)
{
    var obj_required;
    if(typeof window[v] == 'object')
    {
        obj_required = window[v];
        if(obj_required.imgSrc)
        {
            arr_instances.push(obj_required);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can iterate withing arr_instance and do whatever I want to do.

```
for(var i=0; i<arr_instances.len; i++)
{
    if(arr_instances[i].imgSrc == 'requiredImg.jpg')
    {
        arr_instances[i].imgSrc = 'newImg.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any properties or functions unique to this type?

Comment: A possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: No...just consider a situation like, I do not know what does this object look like. I just know that this object might be used in the page and want to figure out the instances. I just know the name 'myObject'.

Comment: I am trying to loop through all the objects in a window.

var scp = window;
for(var v in scp)
{
num_counter++;
if(typeof scp[v] == 'object')
{
num_tryCounter++;
}

In IE11, num_tryCounter is 845 whereas in IE8 num_tryCounter is 44.

I am clueless. Please help.

Comment: @Brian S - What if I have a unique property for this type? Would I be able to look for it? I need it to work on IE8.

Comment: `if (obj_person.someProperty)` will return true if `someProperty` exists (and is non-falsey)

Comment: @Brian S - Thanks for the comment. The worst problem is the concerned object is even not shown up in the iteration when i run the code in IE8 which makes it impossible for me to try anything. Do you have any suggestions for this? I have a code which works perfectly fine for all the modern browsers. However, I have to make it work on IE8 as well.

Comment: Post some code, update your question

Comment: @Brian S - Edited the original question with some more code.

Comment: `obj_person instanceof myObject` returns `true` in IE8, as expected. Why do you think it does not work in this browser?