# TypeScript: get to get Class name at runtime?

Tags: reflection, typescript

In C#, it's easy to get the class name at runtime using Reflection.
Is it possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At runtime you are running JavaScript. So you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) for details.

> Here is a hack that will do what you need - be aware that it modifies
>   the Object's prototype, something people frown upon (usually for good
>   reason)

```
Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

> Now, all of your objects will have the function, getName(), that will
>   return the name of the constructor as a string. I have tested this in
>   FF3 and IE7, I can't speak for other implementations.