# How to narrow types using a property

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to define `getInterface` in this context so that res has the type `number`?

To clarify: I am not trying to write these methods, I have an enviroment where a method exists which returns different objects depending on parameters.type, and I'm trying to find a way to type them

```js
interface A {
  tag: 'a'
  do_one: () => number;
}
interface B {
  tag: 'b'
  do_one: () => string;
}
type Interface = A | B
let one = getInterface({ type: 'a' })
let res = one.do_one()
```

Comment: Typescript 3.2 makes it easier to narrow union types. Take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is not 100% clear, in my reading you what `getInterface` to take the type and return the apropriate value based on the type.

You can do this using overloads or conditional types:

With overloads:

```
type Interface = A | B

function getInterface(v: { type: 'a' }): A
function getInterface(v: { type: 'b'}): B 
function getInterface(v: { type: 'b'} | { type: 'a'}): A | B {
    return null!
}
let one = getInterface({ type: 'a' })
let res = one.do_one()
```

With conditional types

```
interface A {
    tag: 'a'
    do_one: () => number;
}
interface B {
    tag: 'b'
    do_one: () => string;
}
type Interface = A | B

type GetJustTypes = Interface extends infer I ? I extends { tag: infer U } ? { tag: U } : never : never
function getInterface<T extends GetJustTypes>(v: T): Extract<Interface, T>
function getInterface(v: { tag: 'b' } | { tag: 'a' }): A | B {
    return null!
}
let one = getInterface({ tag: 'a' })
let res = one.do_one()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare function getInterface(arg: { type: 'a' }): A;
declare function getInterface(arg: { type: 'b' }): B;

let one = getInterface({ type: 'a'} )
let res = one.do_one()  // res is a number
```

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for all the help! I admit my question was a bit of a mess, I definitely should've been clearer.

Anyway, I managed to get the correct typing -

```js
type FilterTag<T, U> = T extends { tag: U } ? T : never
type Interface<T> = FilterTag<A | B, T>
declare function getInterface<T extends string>(params: { type: T }): Interface<T>
```

which means that `getInterface({ type 'X' })` will always return the right interface, and there is only one union type to edit whenever it needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

It has to be dealt with `do_one()` function basically

```
getInterface(<someparam>):number{
   do_one():number{
      return 4;
   }
}
let res:number = one.do_one();
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to understand typings clearer, typings are present to avoid errors during compilation time. after compilation, the end result will be **pure javascript**.

As for your question, typing can be added only using **or** **|** condition which will be checked during compilation only.

Dynamic typing is a myth yet to be solved.

But there is a method [instance-of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705631/typescript-myobject-instanceof) which can be used.

Comment: I'm not writing any javascript at all here. I'm trying to define the typings for an enviroment where a call to methodA(parameters) returns different objects depending on the value of parameters.type. I'd know how to do this if I could just write it in javascript :P