# How to get javascript object type in a string format?

Tags: javascript, instanceof, typechecking

I am working in JavaScript where I need to check the `instanceof` a custom JavaScript object & if the instance of that object is customTypeA then I need perform certain functions, where as in all other cases, we need to perform some different set of logic.

**More detailed scenario**:

We have generic form submit button which gets included on all form pages. Now we have a common JavaScript for form submit and specific JavaScript files for each form pages. Each of these specific JavaScript files create an object with name of `commonObjectName`. Where on form submit JavaScript calls validate & submit on `commonObjectName`, which will in turn invoke validate & submit for the respective JavaScript instance.

Now, when I need to perform certain checks between validate & submit actions for form A, where as they are not needed for form B, so I wrote below code in formSubmit.js

```
var commonObjInstanceOfFormA = commonObjectName instanceof FormAJavascript;
if(commonObjInstanceOffFormA) {
    //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

Now, the problem occurs when I am on Form B. `FormAJavascript` type gives a reference error since it is not included on form B at all.

Is there a way to find the type of contructor of `commonObjectName` in a string format or find the instance of the object in efficient way so that I can perform a different set of logic for type A & different for Type B?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: FTR this is indicative of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check for it with good old `typeof commonObjectName != 'undefined'`? It will do the check first and only if it succeeds in finding `commonObjectName` it will then try to match it by type, then repeat same for objectB on formB.

```
var commonObjInstanceOfFormA = typeof commonObjectName != 'undefined' &&  commonObjectName instanceof FormAJavascript;
var commonObjInstanceOfFormB = typeof commonObjectName != 'undefined' &&  commonObjectName instanceof FormBJavascript;
if(commonObjInstanceOffFormA) {
    //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: commonObjectName will be defined on all forms, so type of that variable is never going to be undefined unless it is not a form page at all. However, thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

Declare any types you subsequently want to test against whilst preserving them if they exist:

```
var FormAJavascript = FormAJavascript || null;
```

Test with:

```
if (FormAJavascript != null && commonObjectName instanceof FormAJavascript)
```

Comment: This approach also gives ReferenceError since FormAJavascript is never imported & page doesn't know about its existence.

Comment: It won't because its declared with `var` - http://jsbin.com/moroqi/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up using my form page id to confirm which form this is, I am trying to get formId in javascript & asserting it against string 'formA'. If assertion succeeds, then it means it is form A.

I would still like to have an elegant way of finding the form, instead of checking for form id on every single form. But atleast this works.