# How to get the class name of an Object in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Question is very Simple. If you instance, for example, a Buffer you do:

```
b = new Buffer(0);
```

then you check the type:

```
typeof b;
```

The result is 'Object', but I want to know it is a Buffer.

If you made this in the node console you get it:

> >b = new Buffer(1024);
>   >typeof b
>   'object'
>   > b
>   <Buffer ...>

So, some how the console knows that b is a Buffer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: Note: [`Buffer.isBuffer()`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_isbuffer_obj) and (in 0.11+) [`util.isBuffer()`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.13/lib/util.js#L581-L584).

Comment: @maximkou Good answer, but it's part of Ecmascript 6 and therefor not universally supported. Also fails on `var Apple = function() {}`.

Comment: @Bart, `var Apple = function() {}`, yes but this is a good starting point for @user3242467. I think using `instanceOf` is not a better solution for some situations.

Comment: @Bart With the mention of [tag:nodejs], cross-browser/-engine support may not be a concern (though is still good to mention) and V8 has supported `function.name` despite it being so far unofficial. Also, in the case of `Apple`, the constructor itself is anonymous, so the console wouldn't show a name either. `console.log(new Apple()) // {}`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Buffer can be used in browsers using browserify. Also, even though Buffer is used as an example, the question is a generic question, and `b instanceof Buffer` is the most correct generic answer. Also note that `Buffer.isBuffer` uses `util.isBuffer`, which in turn simply checks if `arg instanceof Buffer`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case:

```
b = new Buffer(1024);
if (b instanceof Buffer) {
  ...
```

More generally, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript).