# Any special reason for `arguments` to be an object

Tags: javascript

So I was coding today and I found odd that

```
arguments.concat(someNumber);
```

gave me an error for undefined function. At first I thought that `arguments` might be some kind of native object for performance reasons, but in the end I found out it is in fact a plain javascript object and not an array or internal native object. I was left wondering if there is any special reason for that.

Comment: It's really not a "plain JavaScript object". It's got special properties.

Comment: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) *is* a native object. What made you think it isn't?

Comment: @Bergi yes it's a native object; sorry if my statement was unclear. The `arguments` object has [it's own section in the language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6).

Comment: Note that `arguments` is still "array-like" and some of the Array methods will work. You just need to call them differently: `var args = Array.prototype.concat.slice(arguments);` By using `slice` in particular, you can effectively "copy" the arguments into a real array, at which point all of the methods are available directly on the array instance.

Comment: @Pointy @Bergi odd, `typeof arguments` is giving me `"object"` and 
`arguments instanceof Object` is giving me true in chrome. Shouldn't it show `[Native something]'?

Comment: @Hoffmann: both happens for an `[]`, a `document` or a regex as well. If you want something special, try `""+arguments`: `"[object Arguments]"`

Comment: Interesting, thank you Bergi

Comment: Sadly the `typeof` operator is somewhat inadequate in JavaScript. @PlatinumAzure you're right, but it should be noted that most uses of the `arguments` object endanger runtime optimization, and passing `arguments` out of a function (like, to `.slice()`) is one of those uses.

Comment: [See this interesting article (which appears to be kept up-to-date, at least for now).](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)

Comment: @Pointy you know if there is any performance degradation on using `someFunction.apply(someObject, arguments)`? I use that kind of expression all the time...

Comment: @Hoffmann that article I linked says it's OK, towards the end of that section. However it says it in a somewhat confusing way; maybe I'll log an issue since it is on GitHub after all :)

Comment: `function toType(x) { return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase(); }` is a nice 1-line replacement for `typeof` that I use regularly.

Comment: @Andy: [There are simpler ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332429/1048572) without regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arguments` object is special ("exotic" in Harmony parlance) because it maintains the live connection between its own numeric properties and scope variables:

```js
function x(a) {
    arguments[0] = 42;
    document.write(a);
}

x(10)
```

To support this functionality, `arguments` needs to override [a lot of stuff](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) from the default object. That's why it's a separate type.

Comment: I wonder why they did it like this, this breaks all the rules of normal javascript objects. I assume it is for performance reasons (avoiding allocating the function parameters twice).