# Parse.com: Get Parse.Object class name

Tags: javascript, class, parse-platform

How does one get the name of the Parse.Object instance (using Parse.com JavaScript SDK)? Say, I have a custom class called `Contact`, how do I check that an object is of class named `Contact`?

I tried the following `console.log`s following recommendations from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript), but none of the logs contain any reference to the `Contact` class:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(contact));
console.log(contact.constructor);
console.log(contact.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to know the corresponding Parse Classname for an object, this should be accessible through the `className` property of an object.

Here is a small Cloud Code function as an example that returns the object and the classname. However this is quiet pointless as you already know the classname of an object as you have to use it for your query.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("classname", function(req, res) {
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
    var query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);
    query.first({
        success: function(obj) {
            res.success({
                object: obj,
                class: obj.className
            });
        },
        error: function(err) {
            res.error(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Björn, this is what I was looking for. It may be, as you say, pointless in your example, but in my case it's very useful. Thanks again!