# JavaScript: 'typeof' operator does not return correct classtype

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, typeof

Probably I'm making a huge mistake. Currently I'm trying to declare two classes like the following. But in both the cases, 'typeof' is returning 'object'. What is the correct process to declare a class in JavaScript, so that, we can get the correct class name as by the 'typeof' operator.

```js
var Furniture = function(legs){
  this.legs = legs;
};
Furniture.prototype.getLegs = function(){ return this.legs; };

var Chair = function(){
  Furniture.call(this, 4);
};
Chair.prototype = Object.create(Furniture.prototype);


var a = new Furniture(12);

var b = new Chair();

console.log(typeof a);
console.log(typeof b);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: typeof does not return classnames, it returns, well, type names. If you want to extract Furniture or Chair, use instanceof.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/332422/1207195. For example: `a.constructor.name` and `b.constructor.name`.

Comment: I don't know, why this question has gotten a down vote. I may not know complicated concepts of JavaScript. So, can I not ask that to a community? I think this is quite insulting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check `instanceof` instead of `typeof`.

`typeof` will give you only the data type which is object.

```
console.log(a instanceof Furniture);
console.log(b instanceof Chair);
```

Refer **[How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)**
The above SO shows various ways to find the constructor name.

Answer (score 1):

It's the correct behavior. [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) has useful table with results description of typeof operator:

[image: typeof return values]

I think it'll be really usefull to learn about js a bit. Javascript look like simple language. It's not true. It's tricky one.

Comment: "Correct" is a little offensive. It's what was written down in the language spec, but, it's a bad spec, so it's misleading a lot of Javascript developers expecting classes to behave like... classes.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
    var toType = function(obj) {
        return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
   }

var b = new Chair();

console.log(toType(b));  // Chair
```

Visit here 
 [typeOf Does not return correct class type](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/#more-2838)

Comment: This still returns "object" for me. What is it supposed to do?