# Dynamic Route Loading in Angular 2 Fails. (Beta)

Tags: angularjs, routes, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I want to load routes for the @RouteConfig Dynamically from a service which fetches in format JSON,

```
[
  { "path" : "/about" , "name" : "About" , "component" : "AboutComponent" },
  { "path" : "/contact" , "name" : "Contact" , "component" : "ContactComponent" }
]
```

Following is the code for pushing it into the RouteDefinition Array,

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  //console.log(data[i].path+" "+data[i].name+" "+data[i].component);
  this.routeConfigArray.push({ //routeConfigArray : RouteDefinition
    'path': data[i].path,
    'name': data[i].name,
    'component': data[i].component
  });
  this._router.config(this.routeConfigArray);   // THIS FAILS TO CONFIG PATHS ON ROUTER
}
```

The `'component':data[i].component` requires Classname, where as it recieves a it via a String class. How do i convert the string containing classname into a class??

Also i have tried the Route class using :

```
this.routeConfigArray.push(new Route({path: data[i].path, name: data[i].name, component:data[i].component}));
```

Console Error:

> Component for route "/about" is not defined, or is not a class.
>   i have tried numerous ways like using `eval("new "+data[i].component+"()); || new window[data[i].component] .`

I am stuck at this and really confused as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried `eval(data[i].component)`? The problem with this, besides the usage of `eval()` on external data, is that it needs the `import` statement of this component as well `import {AboutComponent} from "path/to/component/about.component";`. And i am not sure how you would be able to do this..

Comment: @PierreDuc I do have the `import {AboutComponent}  from './about/about.component';` But doing `var testClassName =eval(data[i].component);` cause the error **AboutComponent is not defined**

Comment: Well, try the `eval(data[i].component)` :)

Comment: Im sorry @PierreDuc but it results into the same thing, lets say i do a `var testClassName = new AboutComponent(); console.log(testClassName.constructor.name)` Outputs correctly to **AboutComponent** instead of the previous undesired version **string**

Comment: Ah, i understand why `eval` is not working. If you look at the generated `js`, you can see that it imports `AboutComponent` probably something like `about_component_1.AboutComponent`. So if you can convert the camelCase to underscore. Make it all lowercase, and add a `_1`. Put that result in a variable named, `something`. You can do `eval(something[data[i].component])`. Obviously the compiled javascript is subject to change, and this is probably a very bad approach, but you can try :D. Although, the compiler probably doesn't create that variable, because you don't really use that Component

Comment: @PierreDuc you are absolutely right!!!!!...thanku so much for pointing it out. it does get compiled to ` about_component_1.AboutComponent ` . But now in the scenario u have suggested the `something` must be hardcoded for every such component, i do not want that, i know the imports must be present but the flow of what routes to be loaded must be dynamic from a existing set of routes. I hope you got my scenario. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I am going to post something as an answer to be able to add real code, maybe it will help you

Comment: thankyou so much @PierreDuc +1...really gr8 of u... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript compiles imports into javascript in a certain way, you can try something like this to be able to use `eval()` (cringe). This obviously won't work if typescript compiles differently, but it is fun to check out if this works any ways :)

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  this.routeConfigArray.push({ //routeConfigArray : RouteDefinition
    path: data[i].path,
    name: data[i].name,
    component: getComponent(data[i].component)
  });
  this._router.config(this.routeConfigArray);   
}

function getComponent(comp : string) : Function {
    //convert camelCase to underscore notation
    let component : string = comp;
    component = component[0].toLowerCase() + component.slice(1);
    component = component.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(match) {
        return '_' + match.toLowerCase();
    });
    component += '_1';
    return eval(component[comp])
}
```

**ADDENDUM**

As addition to your own solution with using a `AsyncRoute`, I believe you actually got quite a good solution going on. Perhaps if you place all the pages in a certain way, you can extract the `resource` location from the `path`, but that is not necessary. (i mean to get from the `path` string `/about` to the `resource` string `./app/about/about.component` shouldn't be hard with a small algorithm. But that might be something for an update.

Anyways, you can try something like this with the `AsyncRoute`

*warning: untested code ahead*

```
let routes : any[] = [
    { "path" : "/about" , "name" : "About" , "component" : "AboutComponent", "route": "/About" , "resource" : "./app/about/about.component" },
    { "path" : "/contact" , "name" : "Contact" , "component" : "ContactComponent", "route": "/Contact" , "resource" : "./app/contact/contact.component" }
];

routes.forEach((route : any) => {
    this.routeConfigArray.push(
        new AsyncRoute({
            path : route.path,
            loader : () => System.import(route.resource).then(m => m[route.component]),
            name : route.name
        })
    );
});

this._router.config(this.routeConfigArray);
```

Comment: @PratikKelwalkar You are welcome. Happy coding with `angular2` :)

Comment: @PratikKelwalkar well done. Just a little heads-up. No need to add `CORE_DIRECTIVES` anymore :) these get added automatically

Comment: Yup :) going a bit off topic, when do you expect a RC of angular 2?

Comment: hey, with angular RC 1 release, AsyncRoute Class has been dropped, any idea how to do lazy loading now?

Comment: How we can import System component inside in .ts file ?

Comment: It should already be 'imported'. Just put a `declare var System : any;` at the top of your `.ts` file so the compiler doesn't care. Or if you want to do it nicely, create a `d.ts` file of System, and add this as a reference

Comment: AsyncRoute are no longger supported.

Answer (score 1):

You are too good @PierreDuc , i was just looking at regex to build the same function, some edits i would like to point out to bring it in working state....

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  this.routeConfigArray.push({ //routeConfigArray : RouteDefinition
    'path': data[i].path,
    'name': data[i].name,
    'component': getComponent(data[i].component).constructor
  });
  this._router.config(this.routeConfigArray);   
}

function getComponent(comp : string) : Function {
    //convert camelCase to underscore notation
    let component : string = comp;
    component = component[0].toLowerCase() + component.slice(1);
    component = component.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(match) {
        return '_' + match.toLowerCase();
    });
    component += '_1.';
    return eval("new "+component+comp+"()")
}
```

Thankyou once again dude, its now in a running mode!!! Phew!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad i could help. Although i would expect that `eval(component[comp])` would already return the constructor and that creating it first with `new` and then get the constructor is overkill.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the another approach that the one from @Pierre and @Pratik based on a method that returns the name of classes:

```
Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
  var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
  var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
  return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

In your component you can then configure your routes dynamically like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.routes = [
    {
      path: '/test', component: 'OtherComponent', name: 'Test'
    }
  ];
  this.configureRoutes(this.routes);
  this.router.config( this.routes);
}

configureRoutes(routes) {
  var potentialComponents = [ OtherComponent ];
  routes.forEach((route) => {
    route.component = potentialComponents.find((component) => {
      return component.name === route.component;
    });
  });
}
```

This requires to know by advance potential components that can be involved in routing.

See this plunkr for demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/KKVagp?p=preview.

See this question:

- [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: awesome! ..the plunkr example helped a lot. Using angular 2 , takes me back to school! ...

Comment: Hey as based on everyone's input... Dynamic routing wont be completely dynamic as **have to use import {ComponentName} from 'path/to/component** or some place other in the code like mentioned above in potentailComponents right? But i have almost found a way without using any imports or mentioning the Component in directive or anywhere else, using AsyncRoute i have almost made it, but again stuck badly, would post code, any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you load 2 new routes? I have this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gEG6TJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

***Update to the first above scenario :***
The above dynamically loads routes on the UI, but for that to happen i do have to mention it in my AppComponent

```
import {AboutComponent} from '/path';
import {ContactComponent} from '/path';

//and then either include it in a directive or mention The component Name some place in the code
```

But this defeats the purpose 'Dynamic Loading', as i have to know which components would be requested and also cannot lazy load them. Say i do that for 500 components, i have to load these 500 components and then just  from a JSON mentioned above i pick which has to be loaded on the UI.

**Solution(Completed And Tested) ==>**
I now do not have to mention the components i want to load in **any import statement** neither in any Directive. **Thererby making it lazy loading and Completely Dynamic**

**How**
By Using **AsyncRoute** Class.

Here's my new JSON
//"route" is to map it to [routerLink]="['/Home']" & "resource" is the actual path of component

```
 [
  { "path" : "/about" , "name" : "About" , "component" : "AboutComponent", "route": "/About" , "resource" : "./app/about/about.component" },
  { "path" : "/contact" , "name" : "Contact" , "component" : "ContactComponent", "route": "/About" , "resource" : "./app/about/about.component" },
  { "path" : "/blog" , "name" : "Blog" , "component" : "AboutComponent", "route": "/About" , "resource" : "./app/about/about.component" },
  { "path" : "/news" , "name" : "News" , "component" : "AboutComponent", "route": "/About" , "resource" : "./app/about/about.component" }
]
```

Now to the code, here i fetch this JSON and add it to the routeConfigArray : RouteDefinition[] and call the Router's .config(routeConfigArray)

```
  let routes : any[] = data; // consist the json data in array


routes.forEach((route : any) => {
        this.routeConfigArray.push(
            new AsyncRoute({
                path : route.path,
                loader : () => System.import(route.resource).then(m => m[route.component]),
                name : route.name
            })
        );
    });

    this._router.config(this.routeConfigArray);
```

And thats how it works!!!

Comment: I have added an addendum to my answer. I believe that might be what you are looking for