# Any caveats using isPrototypeOf in JavaScript to check if a variable is of a specific type?

Tags: javascript

### What I want to do

I'd like to write a function that is able to deal with two different argument types as its first parameter.

To be more specific, the function shall be able to deal with the first argument either being [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) or [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

### My research

I was researching a bit on how to detect the type of a variable, since I'm not using libraries like jQuery or underscore and came across a variety of resources. Those were the best:

- http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/
- [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

I didn't expect that this particular corner of JavaScript is this flawed. The resources above list ways of doing this with `typeof`, `instanceof` etc.

But none of the resources I've found included [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) as a viable option.

### The question

I found `NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myParam)` and `Element.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myParam)` to work quite well. Since none of the resources I've found discusses the usage of `isPrototypeOf`, I'm wondering:

**Are there any caveats using `isPrototypeOf` to check a variable for a specific type?**

Comment: I found it difficult to find to find browser support (namely which version of IE it became available). That would be something to consider. If it were the case it's not supported on all your target browers, you could use the `Object.prototype.toString.call()` trick to get the internal `[[class]]` which you could compare to a whitelist.

Comment: why not using `instanceof`?

Comment: @floribon see the first answer and the links I've posted. E.g. you're not able to use `instanceof` when the object has not been created with a constructor function (e.g. `Object.create`).

Comment: @alex according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf#Browser_compatibility) it's supported everywhere. In my experience MDN is a quite good resource for browser compatibility.

Comment: @rmoestl Saying "yes" for IE isn't as great as support breakdown for IE 9, 10, 11 etc.

Answer (score 1):

My guess there are no any caveats with using `isPrototypeOf`.
However you aren't always able to use `isinstanceof`.
If you have no constructor function and use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) you cannot use `isinstanceof` to check whether object belongs to prototype. However you would always be able to use `isPrototypeOf` to check it.

```
var proto = {
    // some properties
}
var o = Object.create(proto);
console.log(proto.isPrototypeOf(o));
// true
console.log(o instanceof proto);   
// TypeError
```

Comment: So one conclusion regarding the caveats is that OP's function could be called with `Object.create(NodeList)` and be considered as a NodeList instance, whereas `instanceof` wouldn't allow that: `NodeList.isPrototypeOf(Object.create(NodeList)) // true` vs `Object.create(NodeList) instanceof NodeList // false`

Answer (score 0):

A caveat is you can't use `isPrototypeOf` on primitive values (numbers, strings, booleans) because they aren't objects. [Primitives MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

```js
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf('I am string')); // false
console.log(Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(1)); // false
console.log(Boolean.prototype.isPrototypeOf(true)); // false
```

Another caveat is many things are prototypes of an `Object`, like Arrays, Functions, Regular Expressions, Dates, even Elements

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf([])); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(function(){})); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(/test/i)); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Date())); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(document.querySelector('body'))); // true
```

Todd Motto has a nice solution for [reliable type checking](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/understanding-javascript-types-and-reliable-type-checking) Primitives and Global Objects.

```js
function type(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
}
```

However, this doesn't work if checking that a value is an `Element` or `NodeList`. For that `isPrototypeOf` works well.