# Get JavaScript array element object and its type

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating an object using a Web Audio API library:

```
var player = new Pizzicato.Sound({
                source: 'file',
                options: {
                    path: 'file.mp3',
                    volume: 0.5
                }
            });
```

if I log the object in the console I get this image:[image: console output]

What I'm trying to do is to get the type name highlighted in the image, `o.Effects.StereoPanner` and store it in a variable but I can't get it. I can reach the effects array with `player.effects[0]` but that gives me the whole object and not its name. I can't even reach the elements of the array as `player.effects[0] gives`undefined`. Àny clue about how can I get that element and its type?

Comment: What do you mean by getting it *highlighted*?

Comment: I mean in the image

Comment: Is that your entire attempt to access the image in code?

Comment: So, you're trying to get the name of the type of object located in `player.effects[0]`? You mention the property name, but that's just `"0"`.

Comment: I'm trying to get the `o.Effects.StereoPanner` string

Comment: Right, which is the name of the type, not the name of the property. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/332422/215552

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of an object's type in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: You'd probably want to do something like "typeof o.Sound.effects [ 0 ]"

Comment: Sound.effects [0], or player.effects[0] in this case, gives undefined