# Is there a way to dynamically retrieve Reference type fields from Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, reference, google-cloud-firestore, denormalization

I have this function which accepts a `DataSnapshot` as an argument.
My current work around was, I still have to know beforehand, what keys I have on my firestore document.

This is really not efficient enough, I would like to figure out a way to actually retrieve all fields that are reference data types without knowing the keys beforehand. That would make this `Promise` more useful, for instance you can just pass in any `DataSnapshot` and it will resolve into a document with the referenced documents appended.

```
getDenormalizedFields = (data: Object): Promise<any> => {
    const denormalizeKeys = ['refOne', 'refTwo', 'refThree'];
    const denormalizationPromise = new Promise(async (resolve: Function) => {
      const denormalizations = await denormalizeKeys.map(
        async (key: string) => {
          const field = await data[key].get();
          const fieldData = await field.data();

          return { [key]: fieldData };
        },
      );
      const promisedDenormalizations = await Promise.all(denormalizations);
      const denormalized = Object.assign({}, ...promisedDenormalizations);

      resolve(denormalized);
    });

    return denormalizationPromise;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data()` method on DocumentSnapshot gives you a raw JavaScript object with the contents of the document.  You can [iterate the keys of this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) in the normal way you would for any JavaScript object, then check the value for each key.  You can find out if the value is a DocumentReference [by checking its type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript?rq=1), then take whatever action you want with it.

Comment: when I `console.log` type of of each data via
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => console.log(typeof data[key]));

`DocumentReference` are of type object, isn't there a way to distinguish which is the exact `DocumentReference` in JS?

Comment: Check to see if it has the methods you'd like to call.  Or use TypeScript, which makes everything easier.