# Why instanceof HTMLElement return false if element doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript

First, Im away from keyboard, just checking on my phone over jsconsole app. Second, i got a simple snippet like this:

```
const foo = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

foo instanceof HTMLCollection // true
foo[0] instanceof HTMLElement // false
```

I just wondering why foo[0] return false when the element it doesnt exist. Is that caused by undefined element? Or what? Any refer to this? Please give me some quotes, thankyou!

Comment: why would `undefined` inherit from HTMLElement?

Comment: I dont know, i just console foo and it return undefined

Comment: It's a feature of javascript that if you try to access a non–existent property of an object (like `foo[0]`), it returns *undefined* (i.e. the value *undefined*). So your expression resolves to  `undefined instanceof HTMLElement`. I think you know what the answer will be. Incidentally, it is not *required* for implementations to implement prototype inheritance for HTML elements, it's just convenient to do so.

Comment: Please, dont judge me like 'i think you know what the answer would be'. I just need an anwer of 'why' cause I dont really understand about prototype inheritence of the htmlelement. 'Javascript feature' thanks!

Comment: If you don't understand prototype inheritance, how do you understand the result of calling *instanceof*? It just tests if the public prototype of the second object (HTMLElement) is on the internal *prototype* chain of the first object. *undefined* is a primitive value, it doesn't have an internal prototype, it's not an instance of anything so `undefined instanceof anyObjectYouLike` will always return false. If that doesn't do it, I'll write a more explicit answer.

Comment: There you 'undefined is a primitive value and it doesnt have internal prototype' i miss this... ;D thanks you so much robg!

Comment: @Rafv—the algorithm for *instanceof* actually just looks to see if it's an object and if not, returns false, which is just to shortcut the process. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will return a NodeList which is a HTMLCollection. So if there is no element with given class, you will still get an empty Node List.

However, when you try to access oth element, since its an empty list, you get `undefined` (*as rightly suggested by [kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)*). Hence you get `false`.

Following is a sample representation:

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(test))
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(test[0]))
```

Comment: Ah, `Object.prototype`. Thanks a lot man! 'If there is no element with given class, you will get an empty Node List' = empty NodeList, thanks rajesh!!

Comment: @Rafv— *Object.prototype* is irrelevant here, it's just a way to access the built–in *Object.prototype.toString* method which returns the "class" of the *this* value it's called on, it can also be done with `{}.toString.call(...)`.

Comment: @RobG can you provide me your relevant mean please?

Comment: @Rafv—[*Get the name of an object's type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type/332429?r=SearchResults&s=3|112.3930#332429).

Comment: @RobG thanks to your refer, it would be my great dinner tonight!

Comment: @Rafv—generally in javascript if you think you need to use *instanceof* you're probably doing something wrong. It's not a strongly typed language and objects can inherit from anywhere (pretty much), so while type checking has its place, "class" checking really doesn't. Have a look through some well regarded libraries and see how they use *instanceof*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your question is that "HTMLCollection" / "HTMLElement" does not matter.

```
const arr = []
arr // []
arr[0] // undefined
arr[0] instanceof HTMLElement // false
```

Comment: So you're poiting if any array or object is not set (yet), it would return false? @t_yamo

Comment: array is set, but array[0] is not set. array[0] is undefined and undefined instanceof Xxx is false.

Comment: oh, sorry there is type miss `arr instanceof HTMLElement // false` -> `arr[0] instanceof HTMLElement // false`