# How to tell the class of an instance

Tags: typescript, instanceof, typeof

Is there a way of telling what class instance an object is in Typescript? I mean more specifically than just 'Object'.

If you had this:

```
const x : MyClass = new MyClass();
console.log(typeof(x));
```

You'd get:

```
'Object'
```

Then if you did this:

```
console.log(x instanceof MyClass);
```

You'd get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined
```

How can I get it to print out 'MyClass'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the name of an object's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type)

Comment: It doesn't help to know the instance type in TypeScript. In order to `console.log()` it you have to be able to find out the class name in JavaScript, at the run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `x.constructor.name`.

The [`.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property of an object holds a reference to the constructor function that created the instance (the class function) and the [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property of a Function keeps its name.

This is JavaScript, TypeScript is not involved. TypeScript types doesn't help here, they vanish on the compilation to JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks axiac, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @gib65: Note that the name may get garbled by minification.