# Check if types in array matches a value in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm wanting to create a function that will check if an array's object matches a type array.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is

```js
let syntax = [Number, String];
let arguments = [23, 'some string', {some: 'ignored argument'}];

// How would I check if syntax[0] matches arguments[0] without hardcoding
// it to keep it flexible?
```

I want to be able to have some sort of function that'll basically check if arguments[0] matches the type on syntax[0], while also having it to be able to check more than just one, or two, and so on types (no hardcoding `if (something[0] === somethingAgain[0])`), however I have no idea how to even achieve this.

Sorry if this is a loaded question! I'm fine with using third-party modules via NPM if this is a long shot.

Comment: Does it have to be `Number` and `String`? `number` and `string` (types, not constructors) would be easier to achieve with `typeof`

Comment: @georg No, i'd want it to at least work with an object type too, however it looks like the answer below by jack seems to work with that as well.

Comment: See [*Get the name of an object's type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type) for a discussion about types and how to distinguish them. Using *typeof* is likely more efficient than calling a constructor, other approaches are more flexible (e.g. distinguish between functions and plain objects, NaN and number, null, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `every`:

```js
let syntax = [Number, String];
let arguments = [23, 'some string', {some: 'ignored argument'}];
let matches = syntax.every((f, i) => f(arguments[i]) === arguments[i]);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Nope, counter-example: `[String] and [23]`. To fix that, get rid of `new` and use `===`, not `==`

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. I this case, there are many details to explain. Number and String aren't Types, they're constructors and this just works as a quirk of calling those constructors. How to test for other Types like *undefined* and *null*? It also fails for NaN, which is Type Number.

Comment: No worries @RekkisomoHarley, always glad to help.

Comment: Oh, also fails for Symbol. ;-)