# How to check if a function is of given class type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype-chain

I want to be able to check if a function is of a given class type in javascript.
For example, let's say I have two classes:

```
class Horse {}
class Chicken {}
```

And let's say I want to create a function that will tell me if a function passed is Horse, something like that:

```
function isHorseClass(func) {
    // check if func is of Horse class type
    return isHorse;
}
```

The function will be called in the following way:

```
isHorseClass(Horse) // should return true
isHorseClass(Chicken) // should return false
```

Notice that the class is passed dynamically without instantiating the object of a class, so I cannot use `instanceof` to check the type here. Is there a way to check the type of the class dynamically, like in the example above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of an object's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an **exact** match, you can just use `===`:

```
function isHorseClass(func) {
    return func === Horse;
}
```

```js
function isHorseClass(func) {
    return func === Horse;
}

class Horse {}
class Chicken {}

console.log("Horse", isHorseClass(Horse));     // true
console.log("Chicken", isHorseClass(Chicken)); // false
```

...but if you want to also get `true` for `Horse` *subclasses*, then that's possible with `class` syntax (not as much with the older ES5 syntax, but keep reading). You can do this:

```
function isHorseClass(func) {
    while (func && func !== Function.prototype) {
        if (func === Horse) {
            return true;
        }
        func = Object.getPrototypeOf(func);
    }
    return false;
}
```

That works because `class` syntax sets up **two** inheritance lines: one for the prototype assigned to instances, and a different one for the constructor functions themselves. For instance:

```
class Horse {}
class Thoroughbred extends Horse {}
```

That creates these two chains:

```
Thoroughbred.prototype −−−−> Horse.prototype −−−−> Object.prototype
Thoroughbred           −−−−> Horse            −−−> Function.prototype
```

This is fairly unique to JavaScript. :-)

Live Example:

```js
function isHorseClass(func) {
    while (func && func !== Function.prototype) {
        if (func === Horse) {
            return true;
        }
        func = Object.getPrototypeOf(func);
    }
    return false;
}

class Horse {}
class Thoroughbred extends Horse {}
class Chicken {}

console.log("Horse", isHorseClass(Horse));               // true
console.log("Thoroughbred", isHorseClass(Thoroughbred)); // true
console.log("Chicken", isHorseClass(Chicken));           // false
```

With ES5, though (including standard versions of how `class` syntax is transpiled to ES5), you can't do that because they usually don't set up the constructor function inheritance (because you couldn't without ES2015+ featuers). You can get **close** by checking just the prototype chain, though. Combining that with the earlier version:

```
function isHorseClass(func) {
    while (func && func !== Function.prototype) {
        if (func === Horse || func.prototype === Horse.prototype) {
            return true;
        }
        func = Object.getPrototypeOf(func);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**That will produce false positives.** For instance, if I did this:

```
function Horse() {
}
function Unrelated() {
}
Unrelated.prototype = Horse.prototype;
```

...it would produce a false positive for `Unrelated`.

Comment: Arguably, `Unrelated` **really is** a “subclass” (sub-something, anyway) of `Horse` in that example: JavaScript is fundamentally prototype-based in how it implements being object-oriented, rather than the typical class-based approach. JavaScript classes are really just syntactic sugar on setting up the prototypes.

Comment: @KRyan - Yes, JavaScript is prototypical, but I would say that no, `Unrelated` is not a subtype of `Horse`, though as you say there is a relationship of some kind. It just has the same prototype. The *constructors* are different and may give the objects very different shapes (aside from what they inherit from their prototypes).

Answer (score 1):

Just create an instance and check using the `instanceof` operator.

```js
class Horse {}
class Dog {}
class SubHorse extends Horse {}

function isHorseClass(Cls) {
  const instance = new Cls();
  return instance instanceof Horse;
}

console.log(isHorseClass(Horse));
console.log(isHorseClass(Dog));
console.log(isHorseClass(SubHorse));
```

The above answer returns true even for subclasses of `Horse`, if you just want an exact match use `const isHorseClass = () => Cls === Horse`.

Comment: Why not just `cls === Horse`? There's no reason to go through the `prototype` property. But note that this will miss `Horse` subclasses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah my bad `Cls === Horse` just works fine, I've updated my answer to cover subclasses as well!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you see any problems with creating an instance and then using `instanceof`?

Comment: The function may not have the necessary information to create an instance (or the constructor may not even allow direct creation of instances).